# Spring batch -Combining Remote Partitioning with remote chunking

Tags: spring-batch

Trying to see if I can design a job where I need both partitioning and remote chunking. We could have something like Table A holds rows (one of the columns in table A will be the partition key) and for every Row in Table A, we would have Table B that contains many child records for a given foreign/partition key in Table A . We would need to run a query that filters the partition keys from Table A based on a query and for every partition key, process all the child records in Table B (here again we would have several million records in Table B, so we would need parallelism for record processing and hence remote chunking)

What would be the right way to think through the spring batch job design for something like that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNBT5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> so we would need parallelism for record processing and hence remote chunking

Not necessarily. Nothing prevents you from using remote chunking in the workers of a partitioned step, but IMO this would complicate things.

A simpler approach is to use multiple jobs. Each job would handle a different partition and process items in parallel using a multi-threaded step. In other words, the partition key is a job parameter here. This approach has the following advantages:

1. Easier to scale: since you have parallelism at two levels:

   - run multiple jobs in parallel using multiple JVMs (either on the same machine or on different machines)
   - and with-in each JVM, use multiple threads to process items in parallel.
2. Easier to implement: Remote partitioning and chunking are not the easiest setups to configure. Running multiple jobs where each one reads `select * from TableA where partitionKey = ?` items and uses a multi-threaded step (it requires a [single line of code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep), adding a task executor `.taskExecutor(taskExecutor)`) is much easier.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. The reason I was seeing if I can do it as a single Job is because I need to be notified when all the processing across all partitions are done. Each partition itself would have a few million records to process and once all partitions have been processed , we would need to trigger another job/process via an "afterJob" of https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html.

Comment: You can use a job of jobs for that thanks to [JobStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html). It is a step that launches a job (a sub job if you will). So you can create a master job that runs multiples subs jobs and add the listener to your master job.

Comment: I am still considering the "sub job" to do remote chunking since we may have many million records per partition and we do want to speed up the processing of each record.

Comment: Mahmoud , If I were to launch multiple jobs using a JobLaucnhGateway where I use a message bus to load balance the diff jobs to diff workers, what are the constructs available to ensure that a worker doesnt attempt to consume too many messages and start too many jobs at the same time. Since a job launched itself would need to process several thousand records, I don't want the same worker to launch another job and have too many jobs started up at the same time by the same worker.

Comment: To add to the above comment I was looking at https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobLauncher.html which says we can use the SyncTaskExecutor and if I place the launching of the Job within an "onMessage" of a JmsListener I would get some guarantee that only one message and one job is launched and finsiged up before fethcing the next message for the next job launch

Comment: This is not related to the initial question. Please ask another question with all details of what you are trying to achieve and I will try to help.